# Scrapy: Scraping into CSV File - getting unorganized CSV file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am implementing the following code in spider for scraping shoes from an ecommerce website.

```
 import scrapy

 class HugobossSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = 'hugoboss'
 allowed_domains = ['hugoboss.com/de/boss-herren-neuheiten-schuhe/']
 start_urls = ['http://hugoboss.com/de/boss-herren-neuheiten-schuhe//']

     def parse(self, response):
     #Extracting the content using css selectors
     url = response.xpath('//div/@data-mouseoverimage').extract()  
     product_title = response.xpath('//*[@class="product-tile__productInfoWrapper product-tile__productInfoWrapper--is-small font__subline"]/text()').extract()
     price = response.css('.product-tile__offer .price-sales::t Zext').getall()  
     #Give the extracted content row wise
     for item in zip(url,product_title,price):
         #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
         scraped_info = {
             'url' : item[0],
             'product_title' : item[1],
             'price' : item[2]
         }
```

And the shell is returning output normally like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRhf0.jpg

But, the output CSV file looks so unorganized like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqXGd.jpg

I don't get where the problem is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, your scraper has picked up a bunch on newline characters (`\n`) together with the product name.

It also seems to pick up the word `von`, which i presume is not necessary too.

My suggestion would be to do some string manipulation to get rid of them:
`product_title.replace("\n", '').replace("von", "")`

Reason why it's best to use `.replace(x,y)` is because `.strip()/.lstrip()/.rstrip()` would strip down matching characters within the string and may remove necessary characters from your product name.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working .. the output file is organized now